# remainder of polynomials $p(x)$ divided by $ax+b$

Tags: polynomials

to find the remainder of $P(x)$ devided by $(ax+b)$ the following determined 
$$ax+b=0$$
$$x=-a/b$$
remainder equals $p(-a/b)$

now i am confused abour finding remaider of a function as follows
$$p(x+1)=-x^2 -3x +1$$
and 
$$p(x-2)=(x+3)Q(x)+K(x)$$

here $K(x)$ is remainder
i really appreciate if you help me with solving these kind of questions

Comment: The solution is $x=-\dfrac ba$.

Comment: this is the answer since we have to find remainder of p(x) divided on ax+b . in this question there is p(x-2) instead of p(x)

Comment: Oh! I read the question too fast. Your formulation of the question is not quite clear to me. You want the remainder of $p(x-2)$ divided by $ax+b$?

Comment: i want remainder of p(x-2) devided by x+3 . also we know p(x+1)=-x^2 -3*x +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

If $p (x+1)=-x^2-3x+1$, then

$$p (x)=-(x-1)^2-3 (x-1)+1$$

$$=-x^2-x+2=(1-x)(x+2)$$

$$\implies p(x-2)=(1-x+2)(x-2+2) $$

$$=-x (x-3)=-x (x+3-6) =-x (x+3)+6x$$

$$=(-x+6)(x+3)-18$$

Comment: yes thank you i know that...my problem is how i should find remainder of p(x-2) divided by x+3

Comment: @user82906 is it ok now

Comment: yesss thank you so much

Comment: For $p(x)=-x^2-x+2$, I only  find $p(x+1)=-x^2-3x$.

Comment: what you found is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder of $p(x)$ divided by $ax+b$ is $\;p\bigl(-\frac ba\bigr)$. Indeed, the Euclidean division equality  is
$$p(x)=q(x)(ax+b)+r, \qquad r=\text{constant}.$$
So $\quad p\bigl(-\frac ba\bigr)=0\cdot q\bigl(-\frac ba\bigr)+r=r.$

For the problem at hand, we have $\; p(x-2)=(x+3)q(x)+K$, hence
$$p(-3-2)=p(-5)=K.$$
By the first relation
$$K=p(-5)=p(-6+1)=-36+18+1=-17.$$